# using group concat on a union query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

in MySQL or (MariaDB) I am trying to write a query of the form

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(select 'a' union select 'b' separator ',')
```

where select 'a' and select 'b' are complex subqueries yielding just 1 row and col so essentially I want to concatenate 2 strings which are the result of subqueries.

The above query gives an error,  I think I need to create a table with an alias, but I have tried without success, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subquery:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sub.c separator ',') 
FROM (select 'a' AS c UNION SELECT 'b') sub;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=66a0f0bd87d9d2305f98d48699e66159)**

---

Alternatively:

> *where select 'a' and select 'b' are complex subqueries yielding just 1 row and col so essentially I want to concatenate 2 strings which are the result of subqueries.*

```
SELECT CONCAT((SELECT 'a'), ',' ,(SELECT 'b'))
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=048032df3e02494ec7c2e544d1097b27)**

Comment: works!  your second solution was very helpful I didn't see that I needed the parentheses around the (Select 'a'), I had tried SELECT CONCAT(SELECT 'a', ',' ,SELECT 'b') which fails.

Comment: @shev72 - Think of it this way:  When using a single-cell `SELECT` in place of a simple expression, that `SELECT` must have its own parentheses.